# Recurrence relation for multivariate polynomials

Tags: symbolic, string-manipulation, polynomials, recursion, binary

I am trying to define a function which recursively computes a polynomial associated to every binary string:

```
ComputePoly[s_]:=(** Recurse on the string s**)
```

For example, suppose my initial conditions were the following:

```
ComputePoly[""]:=1;
ComputePoly["0"]:=x_1;
ComputePoly["1"]:=x_2;
```

And suppose my recurrence relation was:

```
ComputePoly[u concatenated with v]:=ComputePoly[u]*ComputePoly[v]
```

Then this would describe a homomorphism from the monoid of binary strings to the multiplicative monoid of a polynomial ring in $x_1,x_2$.

How would I implement something like this? Should I even use strings, or is there a better data structure for working with binary sequences?

Comment: What are x_1 and x_2?

Comment: Indeterminates, which generate the polynomial ring.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but do you just want $x_1^\text{# of 0s} x_2^\text{# of 1s}$?

Comment: In the example I've given, that is what it reduces to. There is a much more complicated recurrence that I am currently working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a recurrence:

```
ComputePoly[{}] := 1;
ComputePoly[{0}] := x1
ComputePoly[{1}] := x2
ComputePoly[l_List] := ComputePoly[l[[1 ;; 1]]]*ComputePoly[Rest@l]

ComputePoly[{0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}]

(* x1^2 x2^5 *)
```

Of course different recurrence relationships need different implementations. As you don't mention your actual one it's very difficult to provide more insight